# Exact search in Azure search in Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa, content-search, azure-search

Using azure search in Sitecore SXA 1.7 and it is not fetching exact result likewise if we are using "Test data" in search box then it is showing result based which match "Test data column", "Test Data Column 1" etc.

Code :

```
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Name.Equals(search))
```

Even , tried == operator as well but getting the same result.

Kindly someone assist us how we can get exact match data through azure search.

Comment: Check if Name field is Tokenized or untokenized.

Comment: using azure search and while I am checking its index there is no any field for Tokenized or untokenized.